# How to move Marks on a TeeChart in .NET

Tags: .net, teechart

I have a pie/donut chart with the standard Marks. However, I want all my marks to be displayed at the left of my pie. More specific, I have two values insides the pie, and the first marker I want at the top left, the second marker at the bottom left. I need the CallOuts to connect to these markers.

So I would need to control where the text is shown (maybe with the help of an annotation) but need to be able to "connect" the callout.

How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom marks positions as shown in the example [here](http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?t=960).